# cubic equation has $3$ distinct roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$

Tags: calculus

equation $x^3-9x^2+24x+c=0$ has $3$ distinct roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, then $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor+\lfloor \beta \rfloor +\lfloor \gamma \rfloor =$

and $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor = \alpha-\{\alpha\},\lfloor \beta \rfloor = \beta-\{\beta\},\lfloor \gamma \rfloor = \gamma-\{\gamma\},0\leq \{\alpha\},\{\beta\},\{\gamma\}<1$

we assume $f(x) = x^3-9x^2+24x+c$, using $f'(x) = 3x^2-18x+24$

put maximum , minimum  $f'(x)=0$

$3x^2-18x+24=0$

$x^2-6x+8=(x-4)(x-2)=0$

$x=2,x=4$

put $x=2,3$ in $f''(x)=6x-18=6(x-3)$

$f''(2) = -6<0$ means $x=2$ is a point of local maximum

and $f''(4)=6>0$ means $x=4$ is a point of local minimum

i can not go further

Comment: Perhaps $\;\alpha+\beta+\gamma=9\;$ can help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may assume that $\alpha\lt \beta\lt \gamma$.

We have to have
$$f(2)=20+c\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad f(4)=16+c\lt 0$$
Note that we have
$$f(1)=16+c\lt 0\quad\text{and}\quad f(5)=20+c\gt 0$$

from which
$$1\lt\alpha\lt 2\implies 0\lt\{\alpha\}\lt 1$$
$$4\lt\gamma\lt 5\implies 0\lt\{\gamma\}\lt 1$$
follow.

Thus, since
$$0\lt \{\alpha\}+\{\beta\}+\{\gamma\}\lt 3\implies \{\alpha\}+\{\beta\}+\{\gamma\}=1,2$$
and
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=9$$
we get
$$\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+\lfloor\beta\rfloor+\lfloor\gamma\rfloor=9-(\{\alpha\}+\{\beta\}+\{\gamma\})=\color{red}{7,8}$$

(Since $f(3)=18+c$, we have that $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+\lfloor\beta\rfloor+\lfloor\gamma\rfloor=7$ for $-20\lt c\lt -18$ and that $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+\lfloor\beta\rfloor+\lfloor\gamma\rfloor=8$ for $-18\le c\lt -16$.)

Answer (score 1):

Direct from vieta's relation, we get $\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}+\gamma^{2}=-b/a=9$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).